# Two different ways for reading from stdin

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Hard to google this one, I have this:

```
echo "age" |  while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

but there there is this style:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < echo "age"
```

first, the second style is not quite right, but is there a name for the first and second styles? is there any functional/behavioral difference?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: 1st is **pipelining**, 2nd is **redirection**

Comment: `< echo "age"` will try to read the input from a file named `echo`. `<` is a file redirection. What you want is `< <(echo "age")` or `<<< "age"`
"

Comment: `<(echo "age")` is **process substitution**, `<<< "age"` is a **here-string**.

Comment: But you probably want the heredoc: `while read line; do ...; done << EOF`

Answer (score 1):

The biggest functional difference is that the first (in bash) will run the loop in a subshell.  As a result, `$line` will lose its value after the loop is done.  To avoid the subshell, you can embed the content directly in the shell with a heredoc:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done << EOF
age
EOF
```